# Styling bug in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I'm creating a site with WordPress and am having an issue with IE properly displaying the logo in the top-left corner. Here is the site: http://lindseybakermedia.com/design/GPI/ It works great in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but looks as if IE is ignoring whatever rule that is making the logo fit in the header. Unfortunately, I'm using a WordPress theme so I don't have the HTML or CSS to post, but I thought I'd ask just in case anyone had an idea about how I might fix this. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't have "access" to the css/html, then how to you suppose to fix it? The `<a>` tag around the `<img>` needs to have a `height/width` set on it, as well as `display:block`. Remove the `inline-style: width:70%;` from the `<img>` and it works. You can edit this in the browser's `inspect element` on IE

Comment: @rob-scott I can add styles by way of the child theme, but don't have access to the original html or css. I had to add `:first-child` to the `<a>` but this worked great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add the rule

```
.logo a img {
min-width:100% !important; 
max-width:100% !important;  
height:auto; 
}
```

In your logo tag, in style.css line 80 (ish).
You will need to set the size you want the image in your `.logo a` CSS rule, but try the above first to see if you need to add that as an additional specification.

This will force the image to take the size and shape of the container element (the anchor).

Your image should have a height and width attributes even though they will be overridden by the CSS.

And remove the inline style `width:70%` , from the `<img>` element.